# How can I set date for history application?

Tags: android, datepicker

With titanium appcelerator I am using Android date-picker for dates prior to 1582, the output date different than displayed on the picker ! What to do !

Answer (score 0):

For dates that old, I would consider using a different ui control, do you really need the date picker?

Comment: I think you are right , I should try some other ways, Thanks